# Stopping transition in 50% opacity in Alpine js transitions

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I want to have dark background with 50% opacity when user opens navbar in mobile.

My issue is that I can't make the transition to stop at 50% and have 50% opacity. When transition ends it applies 100% opacity. It happens when I don't write `bg-gray-800 opacity-50` in `button` tag. When I write it behaves differently - it doesn't make any transition.

My code:

```
    <button class="fixed z-0 bottom-0 top-0 left-0 right-0 h-full w-full cursor-default bg-gray-800 opacity-50" x-show="open"
               x-transition:enter="transition-opacity ease-in-out duration-700"
               x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 bg-transparent"
               x-transition:enter-end="opacity-50 bg-gray-800"
               x-transition:leave="transition-opacity ease-in-out duration-700"
               x-transition:leave-start="opacity-50 bg-gray-800"
               x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 bg-transparent"
               >
    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if i understand your problem bad,
but i think you may need to use `:class=" "` in your alpine component.

This example may helps you:

Also check this in alpine documents:
https://alpinejs.dev/directives/bind#binding-classes

 **check this code**:
[live-example](https://codepen.io/pooya_poi/pen/mdBRobM)

```
 <div x-data="{opacity:false}"
         class="ml-5 mt-5">
    
        <button @click="opacity = !opacity" 
                class="bg-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-600 text-white py-1 px-2 rounded-md">change opacity</button>
        <div :class="opacity ?'opacity-100':'opacity-25' "
             class="mt-2 transition ease-in duration-200">
            <span class="bg-blue-500 text-white px-2 py-1">Some text</span>
            <span class="bg-red-500 text-white px-2 py-1">Some text</span>
            <span class="bg-yellow-500 text-gray-800 px-2 py-1">Some text</span>
        </div>
    
    </div>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30588903)